# XPages: add a ResourceBundle Editor to the Domino Designer/Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, xpages, properties-file

I found this properties editor that seems perfect, I have a lot of translations to maintain. I found this editor that seems to be able to handle all languages at the same time, which is perfect for me: https://github.com/essiembre/eclipse-rbe

I managed to install the plugin, but now I have to confess that I'm way out of my league. Stumbling around in the dark...

How to start it, how to use it?

Or is there a better way to maintain properties in multiple languages?

Answer (score 0):

I also have to maintain an application with a multi language user interface.

First of all I also started the attempt to use eclipse plugins for editing Java resource bundles but I am also failed... :(

After some test's with different editors I decided to work with [JLokalize](http://jlokalize.sourceforge.net/).

**My way of proceeding:**

1. Step (Switch to the package explorer of your *Domino Designer*)
2. Step (Select a folder for *export to file system*, e.g. Custom Controls or XPages)
3. Step (Set *filter types* to *.properties)
4. Step (*Finish* the export to your filesystem (or a network file share, if someone else should do the translation work))
5. Open and edit the resource files with *JLokalize*
6. After finishing your translation work you could import the translated files (e.g. *_en.properties for files translated to english) in your application.

Comment: When you use the version control integration you get a On-Disk-Project that removes the need for import/export